# Set Margin for container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hi I have a container.

The .container-fluid is too large as it takes the entire screen and looks a little off and .container is too small.

How can I adjust the size of the container. I see the margins are pretty high but if I try to adjust it breaks my re-sizing.

What is the correct way to change the size of the container.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a second class to the `container-fluid` element. Just name the class as you like.

```
<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-w1000"></div>

.container-fluid-w1000 {
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Left and right margins are pretty high, since `margin-left; auto` and `margin-right: auto` are responsible for the horizontal centering of your div-element.

It's best practice to not modify the bootstrap basic classes. You save yourself quite some time later on.

Comment: I like this answer I need to implement it first before I give you a tick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that a `container` vs `container-fluid` is the difference between responsive and non-responsive to the grid. This is not true...what is saying is that the width is not fixed...its full width!

This is hard to explain so lets look at the examples

**Example one**

`container-fluid`:

http://www.bootply.com/119981

So you see how the container takes up the whole screen...that's a container-fluid.

Now lets look at the other just a normal container and watch the edges of the preview

**Example two**

`container`:

http://www.bootply.com/119982

Now do you see the white space in the example? That's because its a fixed width container ! It might make more sense to open both examples up in two different tabs and switch back and forth.

Comment: No that is not what I'm saying. If I wanted to I would have asked that question.